# plastic scm command line date branch modified

Tags: plasticscm

I am trying to get jenkins to display my branches dynamically to pick of them to build

here's what I'm trying to do

```
def getbranches = ("cm find branches  --nototal --format={name} \"where date > \'this month\'\" on repository \'myrepo@cloud\'").execute()

return getbranches.text.readLines()
```

but date here refers to date created and I have devs who create lots of branches some sooner than others some over 3 months old
I'd like a way to be able to list all branches that were updated in the past week 
is that possible in plastic scm commandline ?
I looked at the documentation and I don't see where I can get something that helps.

any suggestions are appreciated.
thanks

Comment: From your explanation I think the following query should work:                                      
cm find changeset "where date > \'this month\'\" --format={branch} --nodata

Comment: --nodata is not working for some reason, but this really helps I can do unique with groovy I believe and that should give me the list I want

Comment: Actually my fault, it was "--nototal"

Answer (score 0):

From your explanation I think the following query should work:

```
cm find changeset "where date > \'this month\'\" --format={branch} --nototal
```